# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SQL_HLZTBRUASDUURQGIOAYPNRAFC.EMPLOYEE_ID) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I am new to sql and have been trying to figure out what im doing wrong when adding the foreign keys. I am able to create all the tables and everything up to the point where i go to input values for the SALES table. I get an error :

> **ORA-02291**: integrity constraint
>   (SQL_HLZTBRUASDUURQGIOAYPNRAFC.EMPLOYEE_ID) violated - parent key not
>   found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721:

Can anyone look over my code and help me with what to change?

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
 (EMPLOYEE_ID char(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(30),
  Address varchar(50),
  PHONE number(10),
  HIRING_DATE date not null,
  SALARY number(6))

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
 (PRODUCT_ID char(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  PRICE CHAR(5),
  TYPE varchar(10),
  PRODUCT_NAME varchar(30),
  AUTHOR varchar(20))

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
 (CUSTOMER_ID char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  CUSTOMER_NAME varchar(30),
  PHONE number(7),
  ADDRESS varchar(30))

CREATE TABLE INVENTORY
  (PRODUCT_NAME varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
   PRODUCT_ID char(2),
   UNIT_PRICE number(4),
   SHELF_LOCATION varchar(2),
   CURRENT_INVENTORY number(3),
   MONTHLY_PURCHASES number(3))

CREATE TABLE SALES
 (TRANSACTION_ID char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  PRODUCT_ID char(5),
  SELL_DATE date not null,
  CUSTOMER_ID char(5),
  UNITS_SOLD number(2),
  EMPLOYEE_ID char(10),
  SALES_AMOUNT decimal(10,2), 
  CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID)
      REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID), 
  CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_ID
    FOREIGN KEY(PRODUCT_ID)
      REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID), 
  CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
      REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID))
```

When inserting the code below is when I get an error:

```
INSERT INTO SALES
  VALUES('1','42','01-JAN-2015','4269','3','5678901234','135.00’)
```

Comment: Defining a foreign key on a table column means that any record in that table must have **a matching record in the referenced table**. So your foreign key on EMPLOYEE_ID means you cannot insert a record in SALES before you have inserted the appropriate record into EMPLOYEE. You'll also need parent records in CUSTOMER and PRODUCTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The employee_id 5678901234 doesn't exist in the EMPLOYEE table.

Which causes the foreign key constraint on EMPLOYEE_ID to complain.
Those foreign key's are there to ensure referential integrity after all.
(The constraint is used to give a name to it)

So add the user with that id to the EMPLOYEE table first.

An extra advice.
It's safer to list the column names in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Thank you. Adding in the data like you said took care of the error.